# If $G $ is a group of order $12$ not isomorphic to $A_4$ then does $G$ have an element of order $6$ ?

Tags: finite-groups, group-isomorphism

If $G $ is a  group  of order $12$ not isomorphic to $A_4$ then does $G$ have an element of order $6$ ? ( By Cauchy's theorem I can show that there are elements of order $2$ and $3$ but cant proceed further , please help )

Comment: Assuming that $G$ has no element of order 6 is equivalent to the centralizer of a 3-Sylow having order 3. The normalizer of a 3-Sylow has order either 3 or 12 (Sylow). As $Z_3$ has only one nontrivial automorphism, we know that $G$ has four 3-Sylows and hence four elements **not** of order 3. These are the elements of the (therefore unique and hence normal) 2-Sylow subgroup $V$. As any 3-Sylow acts non-trivially on $V$, we can exclude $V=Z_4$ and get $V=Z_2\times Z_2$ with the elements of order 3 permuting the elements of order $2$. That's $A_4$.

Answer (score 0):

There are five isotopy classes of groups of order $12$. One is the [alternating group $A_4$](http://ericmoorhouse.org/pub/bol/htmlfiles12/12_3_1_0.html), whose elements are the identity (order $1$), three products of two disjoint transpositions (order $2$) and eight $3$-cycles (order $3$).

All of the remaining four have elements of order $6$:

- [abelian group with $2$ elements of order $6$](http://ericmoorhouse.org/pub/bol/htmlfiles12/12_1_12_0.html),
- [abelian group with $6$ elements of order $6$](http://ericmoorhouse.org/pub/bol/htmlfiles12/12_3_12_0.html),
- [non-abelian group with $2$ elements of order $6$ (1)](http://ericmoorhouse.org/pub/bol/htmlfiles12/12_1_2_0.html),
- [non-abelian group with $2$ elements of order $6$ (2)](http://ericmoorhouse.org/pub/bol/htmlfiles12/12_7_2_0.html).